# Receive Text Message (SMS) in a .net API

Tags: asp.net-web-api, twilio, twilio-api, sms-gateway

How do we receive text messages in a .net API?

Ex. Someone send a text message to my number, I need to the text message in my asp.net web API.
How can we implement this?

Comment: read docs https://www.twilio.com/docs/libraries/csharp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Twilio evangelist here.

This blog post has the code you need and a link to a video that show you how to receive a text message via Twilio.

https://www.twilio.com/blog/2016/09/an-easy-way-to-receive-an-sms-message-with-c-and-twilio.html

Hope that helps.

Comment: I looked at this one, I need to register a public facing API to get the messages I receive on Twilio number. Is there a way to call our side using an API to get the messages from Twilio?

Comment: Sure, use the REST API to poll for new messages.  You could also look at using Twilio Functions to handle the incoming messages.

Comment: Is there a way to validate the the webhook URL? anyone with the URL can mimic the values and send sms to our system right?

Comment: I have a .net core REST API web hook to receive text message to my a Twilio Number in my app. [HttpPost]
                public void SaveTextMessage(TextMessage textInfo)
        { ... code to save message } => here what should be my return type? I'm getting an error "Invalid Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8 supplied"

Comment: The Content-Type should be `text/xml`